# Framer Motion wavy text animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I am trying to create a wavy text animation where I am getting the text from an array. And if the first text completes its animation then it should start hiding and another text from the array should start the animation.

**codesandbox link**: https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-cdn-hjnxyh?file=/src/animated-text.jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a two second duration with a 0.5 delay you can have a setInterval with an interval calculated from those two values on every step. Once you reach the last element you can clear your interval. The interval should just call setItems to update the state to the next value. I haven't tested anything nor I have some code to share but it sounds like a state update thing that can be handled in such way.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const TextVariants = {
  offscreen: {
    opacity: 0
  },
  onscreen: {
    opacity: 1
  },
  exit: {
    opacity: 0
  }
};

export default function FramerHeadline() {
  const texts = ["react", "nextjs", "gatsby"];
  const [currentWord, setCurrentWord] = useState(-1);

  useEffect(() => {
    let i = 0;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (i === texts.length) clearInterval(interval);
      else setCurrentWord(i);
      i++;
    }, 2100 + texts[i].length * 0.25);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <motion.span
      className="animated-headline"
      transition={{ staggerChildren: 2 }}
    >
      {texts.map((word, index) => (
        index === currentWord
        ? (<motion.span>
              {word.split("").map((r, id) => (
                <motion.span
                  initial="offscreen"
                  animate="onscreen"
                  exit="exit"
                  variants={TextVariants}
                  transition={{
                    duration: 2,
                    delay: id * 0.25
                  }}
                  key={index}
                >
                  {r}
                </motion.span>
              ))}
            </motion.span>
          )
        : null
      ))}
    </motion.span>
  );
}
```

Comment: value is changing but the animation is not working.

Comment: I edited my answer by playing around with your code sandbox. It should work now.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just want to know one more thing. How can I activate the loop?

Comment: You can do this by passing a dependency to your useEffect() dependency array that arrives to that component through props. Then from a component higher in the hierarchy, ( for example App.js ) you can update that prop and the useEffect() will be retriggered. It can be something simple, like a state controlled number that you increment.

Comment: if (i === texts.length) {
        setCurrentWord(0);
        i = 0;
      } else setCurrentWord(i);


Is this code ok?

Comment: Yeah that can do it as well if you want it to loop indefinetely. If you want to control it you can do it with dependencies and let react handle the rest.